# Magnetic field lines' parametric form

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, magnetic-fields

Why don't we divide each by $B$ in equation(2) in the following:

We start of by defining a method to plot field lines. For this we will be using the general differential field line
equation. If the magnetic field $\vec{B}=(B_{x},B{y},B{z})$  is known than the field lines of the magnetic field will be defined
by;

$\frac{dx}{B_{x}}$=$\frac{dy}{B_{y}}$=$\frac{dx}{B_{z}}$=$\frac{ds}{B}$  (1)

Where $B=\sqrt{B_{x}^{2}+B_{y}^{2}+B_{z}^{2}}$.
The solution to (1) will give us a single field line 3 dimensional space. In parametric
form, to ease in solving (1) , we write (1)  in its parametric form:

$\frac{dx}{ds}$=$B_{x}$,
$\frac{dy}{ds}$=$B_{y}$,
$\frac{dz}{ds}$=$B_{z}$   (2)